# Regular Expression help needed to convert lst file to csv

Tags: regex, export-to-csv

I have a file (ratings.lst) downloaded from IMDB Interfaces. The content appears to be in in the following format :-

```
Distribution   Votes      Rating  Title
0000001222     297339     8.4     Reservoir Dogs (1992)
0000001223     64504      8.4     The Third Man (1949)
0000000115     48173      8.4     Jodaeiye Nader az Simin (2011)
0000001232     324564     8.4     The Prestige (2006)
0000001222     301527     8.4     The Green Mile (1999)
```

My aim is to convert this file into a CSV file (comma separated) with the following desired result (example for 1 line) :

```
Distribution   Votes      Rating  Title
0000001222,    301527,    8.4,    The Green Mile (1999)
```

I am using textpad and it supports regex based search and replace. I'm not sure what type of regex is needed to achieve the above desired results. Can somebody please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember to quote fields that contain your separator. FWIW I think the easiest solution for someone who can't even come up with a regex for this is to load the data into Excel and export as CSV.

Comment: Hi Joey, this is a very large file about 200k records. I cannot manually add quote against all the individual record sets. I just tried the option of loading the file directly into excel and save it in csv. However it still didnt work as it left with one column having all data. Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: [Do it in Excel using the "Text to columns" feature](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214261) - you will want to use "fixed width columns".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other regular expressions are somewhat overcomplicated. Because whitespace is guaranteed not to appear in the first three columns, you don't have to do a fancy match - "three columns of **anything** separated by whitepace" will do.

Try replacing `^(.+?)\s+(.+?)\s+(.+?)\s+(.+?)$` with `\1,\2,\3,"\4"` giving the following output (using Notepad++)

```
Distribution,Votes,Rating,"Title"
0000001222,297339,8.4,"Reservoir Dogs (1992)"
0000001223,64504,8.4,"The Third Man (1949)"
0000000115,48173,8.4,"Jodaeiye Nader az Simin (2011)"
0000001232,324564,8.4,"The Prestige (2006)"
0000001222,301527,8.4,"The Green Mile (1999)"
```

Note the use of a non-greedy quantifier, `.+?`, to prevent accidentally matching more than we should. Also note that I've enclosed the fourth column with quote marks `""` in case a comma appears in the movie title - otherwise the software you use to read the file would interpret `Avatar, the Last Airbender` as two columns.

The nice tabular alignment is gone - but if you open the file in Excel it will look fine.

[Alternately, just do the entire thing in Excel.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214261)

Comment: Li-aung , Solutions provided by you on the both the approaches worked just fine with some minor tweaking.

I tried using the regex you provided with Notepad++ but only with this modification below I got the desired result <br>
^(.+?)\s+(.+?)\s+(.+?)\s+(.+?)\s+(.+?)$ <br>
\1,\2,\3,"\4"

Comment: And text to column in excel just eased the entire thing for me. Thanks for the wonderful suggestion.

Also I would like to appreciate the efforts of Leonard, dudle0r and OmegaMan. I did try all of our provided approaches and learned more about regex with your inputs. Thanks once again to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

- Press F8 to open Replace dialog
- Make sure Regular Expression is selected
- In Find what: put: `^([[:digit:]]{10})[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]- {1,2}\.[[:digit:]])[[:space:]]+(.*)$`
- In Replace with: put `\1,\2,\3,"\4"`
- Click Replace All

[image]

*Note:* This uses 1 or more spaces between fields from ratings.lst - you might be better off specifying the exact number of spaces if you know it.

*Also Note:* I didn't put spaces between the comma seperated items, as generally you don't, but feel free to add those in

*Final Note:* I put the movie title in quotes, so that if it contains a comma it doesn't break the CSV format. You may want to handle this differently.

Comment: Yes I tested with your given example. Maybe you could upload a more substantial set? By the way - make sure your cursor is at the start of the file when searching...

Comment: Hi Leonard. 
These are the specifics you have asked for 
Data for Distribution Column always starts at col 8 ends at col 16.
Votes may not start before at col 20 but always end at col 24.
Ratings always start at col 29 and ends at 31. 
Title always start at col 34 and can end anywhere based on the length. 

I did try your solution but textpad shows -  Cannot find regular expression. Is there something I'm missing here

Comment: Yes, I think you must be missing something simple. I copied & pasted your example and it works just fine. In fact, with the `[[:space:]]` characters being 'one or more' it should match anyway. Have you changed the regex engine TextPad is using, per-chance?

Comment: I have added an image for you to compare your own Replace dialog window to mine, see my original answer :)

Comment: Oh - apart from in that image I forgot the quotes around the \4 - sorry

Answer (score 0):

First replace all `"` with `""` then do this:

Find: `^\([0-9]+\)[ \t]+\([0-9]+\)[ \t]+\([^ \t]+\)[ \t]+\(.*\)`
Replace with: `\1,\2,\3,"\4"`

Comment: I do not have any single quote " or double quotes "" inside the file. Will your regex work without them ?

Comment: This doesn't work for me in TextPad. \t is probably the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

*MY BAD* This is a C# program. I will leave it up for an *alternate* solution.

The ignorepattern whitespace is for commenting the pattern.

This will create data which can be placed into a CSV file. Note CSV files do not have optional whitepsace in them as per your example....

```
string data =@"Distribution   Votes      Rating  Title
0000001222     297339     8.4     Reservoir Dogs (1992)
0000001223     64504      8.4     The Third Man (1949)
0000000115     48173      8.4     Jodaeiye Nader az Simin (2011)
0000001232     324564     8.4     The Prestige (2006)
0000001222     301527     8.4     The Green Mile (1999)
";

string pattern = @"
^                     # Always start at the Beginning of line
(                     # Grouping
   (?<Value>[^\s]+)     # Place all text into Value named capture
   (?:\s+)              # Match but don't capture 1 to many spaces
){3}                  # 3 groups of data
(?<Value>[^\n\r]+)    # Append final to value named capture group of the match
";

var result = Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
                  .OfType<Match>()
                  .Select (mt => string.Join(",", mt.Groups["Value"].Captures
                                                                    .OfType<Capture>()
                                                                    .Select (c => c.Value))
                                                                    );

Console.WriteLine (result);

/* output
Distribution,Votes,Rating,Title
0000001222,297339,8.4,Reservoir Dogs (1992)
0000001223,64504,8.4,The Third Man (1949)
0000000115,48173,8.4,Jodaeiye Nader az Simin (2011)
0000001232,324564,8.4,The Prestige (2006)
0000001222,301527,8.4,The Green Mile (1999)
*/
```